# drop partition using ifelse condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How should the condition be written correctly so that only one partition drops before 10 am, and after 10 am two partitions?

```
      if trunc(sysdate, 'hh') < ('10:00:00') then
    
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SOFT_TEST DROP PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE(''' ||
                          TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate, 'hh'),
                                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') ||
                          ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI''))';
      elsif trunc(sysdate, 'hh') >= ('10:00:00') then
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SOFT_TEST DROP PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE(''' ||
                          TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'hh'),
                                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') ||
                          ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI''))';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SOFT_TEST DROP PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE(''' ||
                          TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate, 'hh'),
                                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') ||
                          ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI''))';
   end if;
```

Comment: `extract(hour from systimestamp)  < 10`

Comment: @astentx select extract(hour from systimestamp) from dual shows me 4, but now 10:57, is it right?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It extracts the in the UTC. You may use `sysdate` converted to timestamp: `extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp))`. Or implicit conversion to number: `to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') < 10`

Comment: thanks bro, one more question, is it possible to specify also in minutes? For example 
if > 23:45?

Comment: Of course, but only in the same day: `to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi') < '23:57'`. Any string format where hours are before minutes and minutes are before seconds will be valid for > and < comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place, I would reverse the conditions of the `IF`:

```
IF EXTRACT(HOUR FROM systimestamp) >= 10 THEN
  ...
ELSE
  ...
END IF;
```

Considering your conditions are alternatives and they cover both states.